# Webpack: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app'

Tags: npm, webpack, requirejs

I am trying to migrate a project from `RequireJS` to `webpack`. I have most things set up, but when I try to run `webpack`, I get the following error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app' in './app/scripts/views/public-views.js'."`

My code is below.

**public-views.js:**

```
define([
        'app',
        'backbone.syphon',
    ], function(App) {

'use strict';

var Public = {};

Public.Home = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: 'public/home',
    initialize: function() {

        //this.model.destroy();
        this.render;
    },
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    mode: 'development',

    entry: {
        appScript: './app/scripts/app.js',
        public: './app/scripts/views/public-views.js'
    },

    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './app/dist')
    },

    resolve: {
        modules: [
            "node_modules",
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ],
        alias: {
            'handlebars': '../../node_modules/handlebars/dist/handlebars'
        },
        extensions: ['.js']
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            _: 'underscore'
        })
    ],

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.handlebars$/,
                exclude:/(node_modules)/,
                loader:"handlebars-loader"
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

As far as I know, `app` is not a module in NPM... so I assumed it was referring to the `app.js` file. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this-- it seems like I needed to include "app" as an `alias` after `handlebars`.

This is what I used:

```
'app': path.resolve(__dirname, 'app') + '/scripts/app.js',
```